# Angular 6 router transition

Tags: angular, animation, transition, router

Currently having a odd issue with setting up a router transition I can't seem to understand, currently on angular 6

appComponent.html file:

```
<navigation-component></navigation-component>
<loading-screen [@fadeAnimation]="prepareRoute(outlet)">
  <router-outlet #outlet="outlet"></router-outlet>
</loading-screen>
<footer-component></footer-component>
```

loadingScreenAnim.ts file:

```
export const loading_screen_anim =
  trigger('fadeAnimation', [
    transition('* <=> *', [
      query(':enter, :leave',
        [
           style({opacity: 0, position: 'fixed', width: '100vw', background:'#ffff', height: '100vh', 'z-index' : 10}),
        ],
      ),
        query(':enter',[
            animate('300ms ease',
            style({
                opacity:1,
            })
            )
        ])      
    ])
  ]);
```

appComponent.ts file:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'root',
  template:require('./app.component.html'),
  animations: [loading_screen_anim],
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'pogo-ng6';
  pagecontent:any;

  constructor(){
  }


  public prepareRoute(routerOutlet: RouterOutlet) {
    const routeData = routerOutlet.activatedRouteData['animation'];
    return routeData ? routeData : 'rootPage';

  }

}
```

and relative css:

```
/deep/ router-outlet~* {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Is there something that I'm not understanding on why the animation isn't firing off currently, also I've found solutions however it interferes with my footer.

Comment: Can you setup this project module on stackblitz?

Comment: Here ya go! Sorry it took awhile
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-route-transitions-eb9s6y

Comment: apologies I forgot to add a mock footer

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-route-transitions-eb9s6y

using absolute messes with the footer placement but I don't /havent seen an implementation that avoids this @ Azhr-M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried making a change in your stackblitz on the routeroutlet in the HTML as follows and your fadeAnimation works:

```html
<main [@fadeAnimation]="routerOutlet.isActivated ? routerOutlet.activatedRoute : ''">
  <router-outlet #routerOutlet="outlet"></router-outlet>
</main>
```

When route is activated, it triggers the animation.  This code in app.component.ts is not necessary when using this technique:

```js
  //  public prepareRoute(routerOutlet: RouterOutlet) {
  //   const routeData = routerOutlet.activatedRouteData['animation'];
  //   return routeData ? routeData : 'rootPage';
```

Comment: Yes I came here to post this! Is there any solution around the footer component being rendered with the router outlet having absolute positioning?

Comment: Regarding absolute positioning of the footer at the bottom, I actually wrote a blog post on this topic at  [http://dev-reboot.com/pwa-navigation](http://dev-reboot.com/pwa-navigation).  I think it might answer your question or give you some tips.